# About page still refers to Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour, mso-mse-split

The [About page here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/about) still opens with "***Meta Stack Overflow*** is a question and answer site for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites".

> [image]

It should be corrected to refer to Meta Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This now has the correct name being served up.